A little issue to build the APK using expo/eas-cli into React Native
I m coding one app mobile using react native and when I try to buil the APK, it show me this error:
I try everything...expo, npm, npx... I unistall and install NodeJs.
 Android build
✔ Using remote Android credentials (Expo server)
✔ Using Keystore from configuration: Build Credentials rfhRYkKIKh (default)

Compressing project files and uploading to EAS Build. Learn more: https://expo.fyi/eas-build-archive
✖ Compressing project files
Failed to upload the project tarball to EAS Build

Reason: Cannot copy 'C:\Users\Raphael' to a subdirectory of itself, 'C:\Users\Raphael\AppData\Local\Temp\eas-cli-nodejs\e8a9f5b8-0995-4d08-bdac-c54506c3325a-shallow-clone'.
    Error: build command failed.


The root directory of the project seems to be your user folder - bad choice. Better create a new subfolder and move your project there. And please this is not a social media site or a forum, just stay professional and only post questions without smalltalk.

And who are using this as a Social Media or something here?
And thanks for your response.

Your original post started with "How re you doing?" - a common social media  / forum phrase that should be omitted for Stackoverflow.
